# init methods inheriting from CCNode

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccnode

I have a question about creating custom init methods in my Player class that inherits from CCNode. Not sure if I need to instead take a different route and create class methods instead:

`+ (id) addSprite: (CCSprite*) sprite andSpriteBatchNode: (CCSpriteBatchNode*) spriteBatch;`
more class methods ....

In `Player` class, I have a designated init method, along a few convenience init methods.
`- (id) init;`
`- (id) initWithSpriteBatchNode: (CCSpriteBatchNode*) spriteBatch;`
`- (id) initWithSprite: (CCSprite*) sprite andSpriteBatchNode: (CCSpriteBatchNode*) spriteBatch;`  *//designated init method*

When I instantiate this class in my Level class I am not able to call any of my custom init methods directly. What I have to do is:

`Player *player = [Player node];`
`[player initWithSprite: sprite andSpriteBatchNode: spriteBatch;];` //not sure if this is even correct or will it leak memory

I think either should work since they are doing the same thing just on at instance level, the other methods at name.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you `Player` inherits from `CCNode` which doesn't provide functionality for sprites or batch nodes simply because a `CCNode` is just a logical node.

If you, instead, inherit from a `CCSprite` you can do easily what you need:

```
@interface CCPlayer : CCSprite
{

}

- (id) initWithSpriteBatchNode: (CCSpriteBatchNode*) spriteBatch;

@end

@implementation CCPlayer

- (id) initWithSpriteBatchNode: (CCSpriteBatchNode*) spriteBatch
{
  if ((self = [super initWithSpriteBatchNode:spriteBatch]))
  {
    // custom code
  }

  return self;
}

@end
```

Now you will be able to do

```
CCPlayer *player = [[[CCPlayer alloc] initWithBatchNode:batchNode] autorelease];
[somewhere addChild:player];
```

Of course this works if your player sprite will be logically a single sprite, if you have, let's say more pieces then you will need to use composition:

```
@interface CCPlayer : CCNode
{
  CCSprite *body
}

-(id)init;

@end

@implementation CCPlayer

-(id)init
{
  if ((self = [super init]))
  {
    body = [CCSprite spriteWith:...;
    [self addChild:body];
  }

  return self;
}
```

Comment: Looking thru your code cleared my confusion, over thinking and confusing myself. I am inheriting from CCNode for a couple different reasons. 1) I only want to inherit what I need(keep objs light) and  2) I will be switching sprites, so composition is my method of choice for using CCSprite. I think I may have confused myself earlier. `Player *p = [Player node];` does both alloc/init, so I can do something like `Player *p  = [[[Player alloc] init..] autorelease];`. Instance methods and class methods should not be an issue. Class methods are convenience methods. Thank you, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was over thinking and confusing myself. Cocos2D has a class method e.g.: `[CCNode node]` method.

I can have as many instance and class methods to create instances of my custom classes. They are just convenience methods.

Instead of using the default inherited method:
`Player *player = [Player node];` => basically does alloc/init

I could use one of my custom init methods:
`Player *player = [[[Player alloc] initWithSpriteBatchNode: spriteBatch] autorelease];

[spriteBatch addChild: playerSprite];` or something....